# Determining at what points multiple variable functions are continuous

Tags: calculus

With a two variable function what is the procedure to figure out at what points it is continuous? Do I basically just look at what points it would be undefined and anywhere between those points it is continuous?

An example would be 
F(x, y) = xy/(1+e^(x-y))

So here I would just make sure the denominator is not 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an elementary function, it's basically the same as in the one-variable case: you need to look out for divisions by $0$, logarithms of nonpositive numbers, etc.  At every point where none of these problems arise, the function is continuous.